# Match on multiple columns

Tags: excel, formula

I have two Excel sheets - both have these columns:

> Col 1   Col 2   Col 3

In the first sheet, I also have an additional column at the end which will be a formula to see  a row with the same three values as above exist in the other sheet. If the row can be found, I want to display 'Yes', else 'No'. I've toyed with VLOOKUP's etc but no joy.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

If your version of Excel have `COUNTIFS`, then that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have countifs formula, you can do the poor man's version (what I did with Excel 2003 way back when) and combine the columns.  So in Col4, put formula

```
=Col1 & Col2 & Col3
```

Then you can place your Yes/No If formula in Col 5.  Suppose the three data points are named cells (this, that, the).  The formula would look like:

```
=IF(Col4 = this & that & the), "Yes", "No")
```